# What is the correct usage of blueprint-typography-body([$font-size])?

Tags: sass, blueprint-css, compass-sass

Recent convert to RoR and I've been using [Compass w/ Blueprint](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/blueprint/) to dip into the proverbial pool. Compass has been fantastic, but I've come across something strange within the Typography library.

The [blueprint-typography-body mixin](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/blueprint/typography/#mixin-blueprint-typography-body-sass) contains the following:

```
=blueprint-typography-body($font-size: $blueprint-font-size)
  line-height: 1.5
  +normal-text
  font-size: 100% * $font-size / 16px
```

My question revolves around "font-size." I'm a bit lost, as I would expect to pass in a font size and have that size reflected upon page load. However, in this scenario the formula seems to dictate a percentage against the default font.

ie:

```
+blueprint-typography-body(10px) //produces 7.5px off of the default font size of 12px from what I can tell.
```

In essence, I'm curious if there is a standard to setting font size within Compass other than explicitly declaring "font-size: 10px".

*Note: The reason I'm leaning towards Blueprint/Compass font stylings is due to the standardization of line-heights, fonts and colors.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the compass port of the blueprint typography is not fully configurable yet. So changing that default is probably not going to give you a proper font rhythm.

However, The next release of susy has a fully configurable vertical rhythm module that I helped build and it's pretty nice.

[Susy](http://www.oddbird.net/susy/)

[Vertical Rhythm Module](http://github.com/ericam/compass-susy-plugin/blob/master/sass/susy/_vertical_rhythm.scss)

Comment: Someone call the 404 emergency response team!

Answer (score 0):

Just read in the discussion on [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/typography/) (Julio Antúnez's comment) that you can adjust font sizes like this:

```
@import "compass/typography"

$base-font-size:   14px
$base-line-height: 21px

header h1
  +adjust-font-size-to(18px)
```

Not sure this is recommended way but it works for me. I just started using Compass & Blueprint so above might cause problems elsewhere.